# start harvest logs from specific day

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, ubuntu-14.04, logstash, elasticsearch-curator

I installed logstash, elasticsearch, kibana, on ubuntu 14.04, I use cca 40 logstash-forwarders (ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04), I am able to receive cca 300-400logs per second, I would like to start harvest logs since "today", not older logs..
I ran logstash a few weeks ago and it still harvested only older logs, and I would like to harvest logs more in real-time.

I tried set filters, work with curator, I tried to google it, but I still dont have solution.

Unfortunately, rotate old logs is not possible in my case, because we have to store older logs for security audit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logs aren't in separate files (where you might be able to come up with a glob pattern to limit what gets indexed), then I would suggest calculating the "lag" (the difference between the event's timestamp and the current timestamp).  If the lag to higher than your threshold, drop{} the event.